# is there anything I can do if I overheat electric stovetop burner

Tags: stove

I must have overheated the burner.  Nothing spilled and the mark will not go away with cleaning.  Is there anything that I can do about the mark on the surface?

Comment: What kind of stove top? Glass? Ceramic? Induction? Coil?

Comment: A picture might be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt the problem was overheating. Probably something on the bottom of the pan burned, or even hard water can sometimes leave a mark.

Try some glass stovetop cleaner and/or a Brillo pad.